# Bug: Oreo keeps changing the notification sound for all apps instead of just one

Tags: stock-android, htc-10

When I try to change the notification sound for an app (e.g.: WhatsApp), Oreo (Android 8) sets the new sound as the default notification sound (changes the default notification sound for the device). What should I do to surpass this problem?

I have already tried a hard reset.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.

Comment: Ok, Firelord. How do I bump up the question instead?

Comment: You can edit it with new details or fix it if there are some errors in it. Editing bumps it. You can also earn some reputation points here by answering or editing  other users' posts. Once you get 75 points, you'd be able to start a bounty on your post to highlight it to other users for a week. I suggest you follow our [help] for more info.